# if condition to check background color of button

Tags: java, android

```
                        if (buttons[2][2].getPaint().getColor()==color){
                            buttons[2][2].setEnabled(false);
                        }
```

and

```
        buttons[2][2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttons[2][2].setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
            PaintDrawable drawable = (PaintDrawable) buttons[2][2].getBackground();
            color = drawable.getPaint().getColor();

        }
    });
```

i have set background color of button but when i check it does not work

Comment: extend your description. What do you want to  achieve and what does not work?

Comment: background color of button is set successfully but now i want to detect with if condition that which button is colored. the if condition i am using is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure Background resource is a color the you can use this:

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) button.getBackground();
int colorValue = buttonColor.getColor();
```

If your purpose is to get the current value of the background color, then you can set the color value as a Tag in Button.

```
String colorValue = "#....."
button.setTag(colorValue);
```

And then get the Tag:

```
String colorCode = (String)buton.getTag();
```

Comment: this is not the problem. i have set the color of button correctly but when i check which button is colored, this if condition does not work